# ActiveSupport::StringInquirer in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a User model with status column. Rather than doing string comparison everytime like this

```
user.status == 'verified'
```

I though I should do

```
user.status.verified?
```

So I added following code

```
  def status
    ActiveSupport::StringInquirer.new(self.status)
  end
```

But now I am getting stack level too deep which is understandable. How do I fix this?

I am using Rails 3.2.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Your problem is that you're calling `status` inside the `status` method, which causes an infinite recursion problem.

Most answers here focus on using ActiveSupport::StringInquirer initializer, like this:

```
def status
  return unless self['status']
  ActiveSupport::StringInquirer.new(self['status'])
end
```

But you don't need it. ActiveSupport adds an **inquiry** method to all strings, so you can do it like that:

```
def status
  self['status'].try(:inquiry)
end
```

This is the same as using **read_attribute**:

```
def status
  read_attribute(:status).try(:inquiry)
end
```

Or you can just call super:

```
def status
  super.try(:inquiry)
end
```

Comment: very complete answer!

Answer (score 2):

Use the following code to prevent the "stack level too deep" error:

```
def status
  ActiveSupport::StringInquirer.new(self['status'])
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want to read the section "Overwriting default accessors" in ActiveRecord::Base's documentation: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html

Essentially you'll use read_attribute and write_attribute (or self['attribute'], like Baldrick pointed) to access the underlying attribute without calling the actual attribute accessor method.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer doesn't handle the case where the attribute is nil. This is better:

```
def status
  (read_attribute(:status) || "").inquiry
end
```

Comment: This could also be written `super.to_s.inquiry`.